# What went wrong in below code?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$retrive=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM oes.questions;");
$questions=mysql_fetch_array($retrive);
?>
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value=<?php $questions["q_no"] ?> /><?php echo $questions["q_no"]; ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
<?php

if(isset($_POST["del"]))
{
  echo $_POST["del"];
} 
?>
```

I want to use delete ($_POST["del"]) function but for debugging I used echo and found that it prints '/' .

Comment: You have echoed the value in `value` attribute

Comment: You should consider using mysqli instead of mysql - this is a good tutorial: http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 value='<?php echo $questions["q_no"]; ?>'
```

You didn't echo the value of the `$questions` index.

EDIT: To help prevent XSS:

Make sure you set the header correctly:

```
 header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');


value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($questions['q_no'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?>"
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that pops out is that you're not quoting the value attribute:

```
 value=<?php $questions["q_no"] ?> /
```

You're also not escaping any quotes from `$questions["q_no"]`. As value needs to be wrapped in quotes, and adding additional quotes will only cause value to get set to the wrong value, its not surprising your getting a strange value posted back to the server (maybe even part of the rest of the form HTML, including the /).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by, You need echo the value and also qoute (') issue. Try this

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value='<?php echo $questions["q_no"]; ?>' /><?php echo $questions["q_no"]; ?>
```

OR

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value="<?php echo $questions['q_no']; ?>" /><?php echo $questions["q_no"]; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value=<?php $questions["q_no"] ?> />
```

You aren't echoing the question, so your HTML is rendered as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value= />
```

Which is therefore parsed as:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value=" /">
```

---

You need to quote your attributes, and also make sure you tell PHP to echo someting.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="del" value="<?php echo $questions["q_no"] ?>" />
```